# Extra space when looping through text file.

Tags: java

When looping through a text file with each item on a different line, the loop keeps getting an extra white space as one of the values.

```
try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Words.txt")); 
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                event.getTextChannel().sendMessage(line + "; ").queue();
            }
            br.close();
    }
```

The result I'm getting is:

廊下;

;

火星;

;

意味;

;

but I want 廊下; 火星; 意味;

Comment: Can you provide an example of some lines from "Words.txt"?

Comment: Your code is not printing anything, it's only doing `event.getTextChannel().sendMessage(line + "; ").queue();`. You need to show the code that is printing things, because that is likely where the problem is.

Comment: I think you need to strip the `\n` but that depend on the word.txt file

Comment: The words appear on each line in the text file. Like [this](http://i.imgur.com/HeTTLYz.jpg). `event.getTextChannel().sendMessage().queue();` prints to a chat in the program discord. It is certainly printing it because I can see it.

Comment: You're not picking up what I'm saying. The newlines are added by whatever code you use to print the messages (since the newline is **after** the semicolon). You don't want newlines between your messages - then you need to fix the code that prints it - in this case your chat program.

Comment: It does this even when I switch it to System.out.print(); though. Is that the same issue?

Comment: Are you sure you line String does not contain new line character? to me it seems like your file is read like this: Char_; \n ; Char_; \n; ... and so on. Why don't you debug your String line? Or try cleaning your string? (strip, remove \n etc)

Comment: I've tried .replaceAll("\n", "") but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried \n \\n \\\\n

Comment: Did you try debugging? Are you absolutely sure that every second String line is not "\n" ?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Are you using eclipse? put break point inside while() and debug. You then can check String line.

Comment: Nothing happens.

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens? If you don't know how to debug, maybe you should read about it...not that hard really. Here's an article: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: Sorry lol. It seems to be giving me "" as the value put into the string, not \n

Answer (score 2):

There could be a cleaner way of doing it depending on your actual way of sending the message as pointed out in the comments. You could however try doing something like this:

```
try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Words.txt")); 
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")).append("; ")
        }
        br.close();
        event.getTextChannel().sendMessage(builder.toString()).queue(); 
}
```

EDIT:
You really should try to find out where the extra empty lines come from, but a temporary workaround would be to skip over empty lines:

```
try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Words.txt")); 
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String stripped = line.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
            if (!stripped.isEmpty()) {
                builder.append(stripped).append("; ")
            }
        }
        br.close();
        event.getTextChannel().sendMessage(builder.toString()).queue();
}
```

Comment: This gets everything on one line, but still has the empty space in between the words. I got this: 廊下; ; 火星; ; 意味; ;

Debugging, its putting "" into it.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by adding if (!line.equals("")) before the line that prints the text.